# What is the wave function?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I understand that the square of the wave function is the probability density of finding an electron. However, what is the wave function itself? I am trying to understand molecular orbital theory but this concept is getting in the way of me completely understanding it. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: A very similar question was just asked recently here: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16467/what-actually-is-the-wavefunction

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a conceptual understanding of what the wave function is. In that thread it was described as a trajectory but there was no explanation. Could you perhaps clarify - at least on a conceptual level?

Comment: @user3764899 quantum mechanics is constructed as derivative of Hamiltonian formulation of classical mechanics by changing operator over trajectory to operator over (time-dependent) field. You can look for more here (warning, hardcore math ahead) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics

Answer (score 1):

- It is often asked "what is waving when a particle is described as a wave?" and the correct response is "existence itself is waving."
- The wavefunction is most elegantly described as a description of reality for your system. You then act on the wavefuntion with a hamiltonian to yeild an eigenvalue to quantify the energy.